# Multiple One-to-many relationships in the same table. The property is not a valid navigation property on the related type

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am having difficulty mapping this relationship.

```
public class Person
{
     public long Id { get; set; }

     [InverseProperty("Friend")]
     public virtual ICollection<Friendship> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class Friendship
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PersonId))]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public long FriendPersonId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(FriendPersonId))]
    public virtual Person Friend { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error

`The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Friends' on type 'Person' is not valid. The property 'Friends' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'Friendship'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property.`

I can clearly see that Friendship class does contain a property called Friend, but I am not sure what makes it an invalid navigation property.

If I changed my `InverseProperty` attribute to `FriendPersonId` it throws a null reference exception.

Comment: I checked and it worked for me . I am using EF 6.1.3  to test is his isse related to EF7?

Comment: What code did you use to test? I am doing something like this.

`Person p = new Person(); p.Friends.Add(new Friendship() { FriendPersonId = 4 }); context.People.Add(p); context.SaveChanges();`, where 4 is the id of a person that already exists in the DB

Comment: If the `Friends` collection represents the friends of the `Person`, then you should tie it to the `Friendship.Person` property (i.e. `[InverseProperty("Person")]`). Then you should be able to use the code from your comment.

Comment: The above model is valid and works correctly with EF core. What version of EF are you using? and what is the code which is throwing exception for you?

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right, I had the wrong InverseProperty. I can't mark your comment as answer though. 

The exception I received occurred while I was modifying my attributes in an effort to get my code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse property was set incorrectly.

Should have been `[InverseProperty("Person")])`

Credit: Ivan Stoev for pointing out my mistake.